# Failed to push selection: Read-only file system - androrid sdcard

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

when i am trying to add mp3 into my sdcard i am getting this error

```
 [2013-01-23 22:49:52 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
 [2013-01-23 22:49:52] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
```

is anybody tell me what is the reason.

Comment: which method you are using to add file to sdcard?

Answer (score 1):

What solved my same issue was: 
1. add the necessary permissions to the mainfest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

1. restart the adb from DDMS perspective
2. restart eclipse.